# Error Installing rJava | Makefile.all:38: recipe for target 'libjri.so' failed

Tags: java, r, installation, rjava

I'm having problems to install rJava package in [MRO 3.3.1](https://mran.microsoft.com/open), Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Ubuntu 16.04LTS 64-bit)  (error messages below).

Following several other reported issues, I installed java-8-openjdk-*, java-8-oracle, liblzma-dev and others. I also tried to install rJava through 'conda install', but it was stored in /anaconda3 directory and I don't know how to turn it available to MRO.

Some clue?

```
* installing *source* package ‘rJava’ ...
** package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
configure: checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 supports static inline...
yes
checking whether setjmp.h is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking whether sigsetjmp is declared... yes
checking whether siglongjmp is declared... yes
checking Java support in R... present:
interpreter : '/usr/bin/java'
archiver    : '/usr/bin/jar'
compiler    : '/usr/bin/javac'
header prep.: '/usr/bin/javah'
cpp flags   : '-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux'
java libs   : '-L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm'
checking whether Java run-time works... yes
checking whether -Xrs is supported... yes
checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... yes
checking JNI data types... ok
checking whether JRI should be compiled (autodetect)... yes
checking whether debugging output should be enabled... no
checking whether memory profiling is desired... no
checking whether threads support is requested... no
checking whether callbacks support is requested... no
checking whether JNI cache support is requested... no
checking whether headless init is enabled... no
checking whether JRI is requested... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
config.status: creating R/zzz.R
config.status: creating src/config.h
=== configuring in jri (/tmp/RtmpzZwPWE/R.INSTALL1f1038e0708d/rJava/jri)
configure: running /bin/sh ./configure --disable-option-checking '--prefix=/usr/local'  --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking whether Java interpreter works... checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... yes
checking whether JNI programs can be run... yes
checking JNI data types... ok
checking whether Rinterface.h exports R_CStackXXX variables... yes
checking whether Rinterface.h exports R_SignalHandlers... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating run
config.status: creating src/config.h
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION    -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -c Rglue.c -o Rglue.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION    -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -c arrayc.c -o arrayc.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION    -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -c callJNI.c -o callJNI.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION    -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -c callback.c -o callback.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION    -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -c fields.c -o fields.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION    -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION    -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -c jri_glue.c -o jri_glue.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION    -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -c loader.c -o loader.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION    -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -c otables.c -o otables.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION    -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -c rJava.c -o rJava.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION    -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -c tools.c -o tools.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/lib -o rJava.so Rglue.o arrayc.o callJNI.o callback.o fields.o init.o jri_glue.o loader.o otables.o rJava.o tools.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/lib -lR
(cd ../jri && make)
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/RtmpzZwPWE/R.INSTALL1f1038e0708d/rJava/jri'
make -C src JRI.jar
make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/RtmpzZwPWE/R.INSTALL1f1038e0708d/rJava/jri/src'
/usr/bin/javac -target 1.4 -source 1.4 -d . ../package-info.java ../RFactor.java ../REXP.java ../Rengine.java ../RList.java ../Mutex.java ../RConsoleOutputStream.java ../RMainLoopCallbacks.java ../RVector.java ../RBool.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.4
warning: [options] source value 1.4 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.4 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
4 warnings
/usr/bin/javah -d . -classpath . org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o Rengine.o Rengine.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o jri.o jri.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o Rcallbacks.o Rcallbacks.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o Rinit.o Rinit.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o globals.o globals.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o rjava.o rjava.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux
rjava.c: In function ‘RJava_request_lock’:
rjava.c:22:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   write(ipcout, buf, sizeof(ptrlong));
   ^
rjava.c: In function ‘RJava_clear_lock’:
rjava.c:30:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   write(ipcout, buf, sizeof(ptrlong));
   ^
rjava.c: In function ‘RJava_request_callback’:
rjava.c:39:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   write(ipcout, buf, sizeof(ptrlong) * 3);
   ^
rjava.c: In function ‘RJava_init_ctrl’:
rjava.c:51:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   write(ipcout, buf, sizeof(ptrlong));
   ^
rjava.c:52:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘read’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   read(resin, buf, sizeof(ptrlong) * 2);
   ^
gcc -std=gnu99 -o libjri.so Rengine.o jri.o Rcallbacks.o Rinit.o globals.o rjava.o  -shared -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp  -L/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/lib -lR -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lrt -ldl -lm -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lstdc++ -licuuc -licui18n
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcre
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbz2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.all:38: recipe for target 'libjri.so' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmpzZwPWE/R.INSTALL1f1038e0708d/rJava/jri/src'
make[2]: *** [libjri.so] Error 1
Makefile.all:21: recipe for target 'src/JRI.jar' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmpzZwPWE/R.INSTALL1f1038e0708d/rJava/jri'
make[1]: *** [src/JRI.jar] Error 2
Makevars:14: recipe for target 'jri' failed
make: *** [jri] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/home/jeco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need the development libraries for libpcre and libbz2.
What distribution are you using?
Assuming it's Debian based, try installing the following packages:

- libbz2-dev
- libpcre3-dev or libpcre2-dev (not sure what version is required)

Example:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev libpcre3-dev
```

Comment: Great @flg !! After almost a month trying to solve this, you finally gave me a solution in 44 minutes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: On my system, `libpcre2-dev` solved the error.

Answer (score 2):

This is and old post I'm bumping, but I couldn't solve the problem with the accepted answer.

In addition to the accepted answer, you may need some other libraries. In my case I just solved it with:

```
sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev
```

but others may be needed. You may want to check https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned/issues/11

Comment: still having issues on Linux Mint based on Ubuntu 18.04 all the libs above are there but still : /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcre2-8
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.all:35: recipe for target 'libjri.so' failed